# A set having no limit point in itself is Countable

Tags: real-analysis

If a set $A$ doesn't have any limit point in itself, then the set $A $ is countable. i.e

If  $A'$ $\ne$  $\phi $ , and $A$ $\cap$ $A'$ $= $ $\phi$, then A is Countable.

It's seem to be true, but I can't prove it.

I know that the result is true if we use the term [**Condensation Point**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condensation_point) instead of limit point.
According to my knowledge **Condensation Point** and Limit point are different, as any **condensation point** can be a limit point but a limit point is not necessarily a **condensation point**.

In this context I want to know the definition of  a isolated set, the definition I know is a set $B $ is isolated if $B$ $\cap$ $B'$ $=$ $\phi$, so according to this definition an isolated set is Countable, right ?

It is very trivial result, but I am stuck at it.Hope to get help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that $A$ is a set of reals and that the reals are equipped with their standard topology.

Fix a countable basis $(B_n \mid n \in \mathbb N)$ for the standard topology on $\mathbb R$. For every $a \in A$ let $n(a)$ be minimal $n$ such that

$$
A \cap B_n = \{a\}.
$$

(Such an $n$ exists precisely because $A$ has no limit points.)

But now
$$
f \colon A \to \mathbb N, a \mapsto n(a)
$$

is an injection witnessing that $A$ is countable.

Comment: How can you expand this for the complex numbers?

Comment: @UsernameUnknown Yes. This works for every topological space with a countable basis -- by the exact same argument. The complex numbers have a countable basis -- e.g. the collection of all $\epsilon$-balls for rational $\epsilon$ whose center is of the form $x + iz$ with $x,z \in \mathbb Q$.

Answer (score 1):

Considering the discret space with uncountable points, it is not right.

However, if $A$ is in a second countable space such as $\mathbb{C}$, your conclusion is right.

Indeed, each isolated point corresponds an open neighborhood in the countable topology basis that contains no  any other point, hence the cadinality of $A$ $\leq$ that of the countable basis.

Comment: I am actually considering the case in the real number system with usual topology !

Comment: so you are right because $\mathbb{R}$ is a second countable space.

Comment: Yes ! Actually you gave a more general result. ..